# Redirect user in Python + Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

I'm trying to do a simple redirection after logging the user. I thought I could use the print "Location:..." method but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        ip = self.request.remote_addr
        log = Log()
        log.ip_address = ip
        log.put()
        print "Location:http://www.appurl.com"
```

Comment: how would puting print statement redirect you?

Comment: how would calling out my stupid attempt help me?

Comment: It is not in any way stupid, you have to start somewhere and I actually tried the same thing when I first started on AppEngine.  The good news is that Google provides great documentation. :)

Comment: @dcrodjer: If he's printing a header, it makes sense.

Comment: FWIW, 'print' could be made to work, but you should never output directly to standard out from inside a WSGI app. Any time you see a 'print' statement, you're doing it wrong. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`RequestHandler`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html) has a [`redirect()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html#RequestHandler_redirect) method that you can use. It takes two parameters, the first one being the url to redirect to, and the second one a boolean value. If you pass true, it sends a 301 code to indicate a permanent redirect, if you don't pass it an explicit value, it defaults to false, and sends the client a 302 code to indicate a temporary redirect.

Something like this:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        ip = self.request.remote_addr
        log = Log()
        log.ip_address = ip
        log.put()
        self.redirect("http://www.appurl.com") # replaced this -> print "Location:http://www.appurl.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to do it directly on appengine_config.py

i.e. if you want to redirect everything to "http://www.google.com" you could add the following:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):

    return webapp.WSGIApplication([('/*', webapp.RedirectHandler.new_factory('http://www.google.com', permanent=True))], debug=True)
```

i.e. if you want to do something based on the host you could do:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):

    if 'mydomain.com' in os.environ.get('HTTP_HOST'):
        return webapp.WSGIApplication([('/*', webapp.RedirectHandler.new_factory('http://www.google.com/', permanent=True))],
    debug=True)
    else:
        return app
```