# How to redirect traffic from a Google Appspot domain to a new site?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a personal site hosted on google's appspot.  I remade the whole site and now I have it hosted on github pages.

The old appspot site gets a pretty good amount of traffic that I don't want to loose.  The traffic is around half from back links and half from search.  I guess I'll probably loose the search traffic?

What's the best way to get the traffic to my new site?  I was thinking that I'd have to do a redirect on each individual page from the old side to link it to the corresponding page of the new site?  If so now can I do that with the appspot site?

Comment: The best way wold be to change DNS record to point to new site, then you won't loose any search traffic. Don't know if it's an option for you, as you haven't posted any.

Comment: Which platform are you using (python, java)?

Comment: Both sites use Python

Comment: David,  The pages on the new site don't have the same name as the pages on the old site. I don't think a DNS change would work because it just changes the domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231254/redirect-user-in-python-google-app-engine

Comment: Hey @JDD , did you sort out this, or can I help you out? You can just have one .py file doing the redirect, and map all the URL patterns to that .py file. For redirect, you can use either Python or just simple JS one line code...